# How to display x-axis label above the axis using AChartEngine in Android?

Tags: android, achartengine

[image: Today Graph]

I want to create graph like above. 
In this graph titles are on top. User can select particular time to view more detail.
How to show this X-axis labels on top of axis using AChartEngine or any other graph api for android?

Comment: did u solved the issue i also hv this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations, which are text labels that can be placed anywhere in the graph.

```
series.addAnnotation("Vacation", 6, 30);
```

Comment: Hi Dan, This is working like charm. Can you tel me how to draw line with annotation. Is it possible that we can create same as it graph like above in android using achartengine library.

Comment: You can add vertical lines by adding extra series, each one defining two points that will actually be the vertical line endpoints.

Comment: is it possible that i will put x-axis on top?