# How can i customize the layout and position of X axis when drawing a graph using achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to construct a graph using **achartengine** library showing some values corresponding to date/time.

The date axis(behaving as X axis) should be present on the top.
 Also i want to customize the layout of  X axis.
I want to show the date on X axis above and for each date there are certain time intervals.

**Example : I want to plot the readings every 4 hours  every day . I want to distinguish the readings day wise as well as hour interval wise.
I hope I am clear.**

Can somebody please help me in achieving this ?
Thanks !

Comment: This is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545194/how-to-display-x-axis-label-above-the-axis-using-achartengine-in-android

Comment: Thanks Dan,This means that we can't put X-axis on the top.